# Why does this ask for user input twice?

Tags: while-loop, user-input

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "";
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do? Enter help for commands.");
        choice = userInput.nextLine();
        switch(choice.toLowerCase()) {
            case "turn right":
                System.out.println("right");
            case "turn left":
                System.out.println("left");
            case "move":
                System.out.println("move");
        }
    }
```

On each iteration of the loop, it asks for user input two times. For example, it requires two lines before reaching the switch statement. Why does this happen?

Comment: use `userInput.next();`, instead of  `userInput.nextLine();`

Comment: userInput.next() would only take and check one word at a time.

Comment: I believe  while(true) will loop n number of times

Comment: The while(true) condition isn't really important, it can be replaced with any true condition. It's what happens with each iteration of the loop that's the problem. It asks for user input twice on each run.

Comment: No, you are writing command in console and when switch trigger it also write command in console, that's why it's look like it is returning twice, your code is working properly

Comment: When you run the code it asks leaves you space to input a line, once you enter something, it again leaves space for you to input a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse glitched and my code ran improperly. Fixed by closing and reopening Eclipse.